# UIViewAnimationCurveLinear Hide View Completely

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to switch between two views by using the page curl effect in `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear` but when I execute this animation, the top of the page curl stays present on the second view. [image]

I implement this action by using

```
 -(IBAction)menu:(id)sender{

    MenuViewController *view=[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    view.modalTransitionStyle=UIViewAnimationCurveLinear;
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];

}
```

Anyone know how to completely remove the previous view from the screen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewAnimationCurveLinear` is not a modal transition style. If you want page curl then you probably want `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`.

Comment: But again, isn't this only a partialcurl and not a full curl away effect that completely hides the first view controller?

Comment: If you want a full transition, use one of the appropriate UIModalTransitionStyleXXX constants.

Comment: But none of the UIModalTransitionStyles does a complete page curl transition. This is what I'm trying to implement for the animation when switching views.